# Wordpress feed with exclusive content

Tags: wordpress, rss

I want to offer my visitors some freebies, but I want them to be available only on the website's feed (to promote it). In others words, I don't want it to appear as a normal post on my website, but only on the feeds.

Is there any way of doing that? I know how to edit my theme files if needed, but if there's a plugin that does the job, the better.

Please note, the offer will only available on the feed, not through mail-lists, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't a programming answer -- unless you specifically want to ask programming-related WordPress questions, you may well be better off asking on [wordpress.stackexchange.com/](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/) -- but I'd just use a plugin like the [Advanced Category Excluder](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/advanced-category-excluder/). You can specify any category of post to be excluded from the archive/home/search pages, or the feed.

So, install the plugin, put the posts you want to be feed-only in a particular category, and configure the Category Excluder to exclude that category from everything except the feed.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't know that there was a stackexchange website dedicated to Wordpress (if anyone can move the post, please do). Advanced Category Excluder worked great after some code fixes, exactly what I was looking for! Thanks Matt!

Answer (score 0):

There are many plugins that will append things to the feed, such as:

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/copyfeed/

That's probably the way to go if you want to offer freebies at the bottom of each post. If you want entire posts, look for some kind of category excluder like:

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/simply-exclude/

One issue you'll run into, however, is that at some point someone will start scraping your feed and republishing it in an autoblog. That's true of anything you do, though.

Comment: I tried simply exclude, but looks to be non-functional for 3.0.4 version of Wordpress. About the feed scrappers, well, its' true! But I don't care too much about it. I just want to attract more readers to subscribe the blog. Thanks for the tips!